# LiveCharts Mark closest point to mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I have a WPF application where I used DevExpress charts to display some data. I want to get rid of them and use LiveCharts, but I want to display a circle in the chart point closest to the mouse cursor when it is inside the chart. I have tried sections and I can show lines that cross in the point, but I can't mark that point as it automatically does when you hover over it. Is there a way to do this without changing the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get your answer from [this example](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/tree/master/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/SectionsMouseMove).

By calculating the closest point to your mouse (like in the example, you can then change the style of your chart point. In the example, the x-axis lable at the specific point gets highlighted.

Comment: how do i change the style of the charpoint? i have tried it but i haven't been able to change it as most of the properties from ChartPoint are set internally

Comment: I think you could use a mapper for it. I havn't tried it yet, but you could have a look at this example: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Point%20State

Comment: I have tried with a mapper and everything works fine!! Thank you!!